AsyncImage inside a Column is fitting the entire height of the screen instead of the width
Having a panoramic AsyncImage which I want to use as a header of my app, inside a lazycolumn (with modifier.fillmaxwidth()), it displays correctly having just the width of the screen. If I switch to a column (also with modifier.fillmaxwidth()), it does wrong. Instead of fitting the width of the screen, the AsyncImage is being painted with all the height of the screen and I only can see a portion of the left of the image, because now the width of the image is super big.
Why does this happen? The column is in the topAppBar of a Scaffold.
Column (
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    HeaderComposable(header)
}

@Composable
fun HeaderComposable(header: Header, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AsyncImage(
        model = header.getImageRoute(),
        contentDescription = "",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}


That's what ContentScale.Crop is supposed to do, it scales the source uniformly so that both dimensions of the source will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the destination.
And if you don't limit the height, it will simply use maxHeight, unless the maxHeight is Constraints.Infinity. In that case it's obviously impossible to fill the height and it falls back to just filling the width. And that's what happens in the LazyColumn, because its children are measured with maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity - unlike Column (without verticalScroll) which has a finite maxHeight.
You have to either limit the height somehow, or use a different content scale, probably ContentScale.FillWidth.

it works with FillWidth, but... what happens if I use a image that 9:16 instead of 16:9? then, only the width is seen. should be better to use Fit instead of FillWidth?

TL/DR1
As i explained below in "detail" AsyncImage calculates dstSize differently than Image when maxHeight of Constraints is Constraints.Infinity you can simply change to that Constraints using Modifier.layout
@Composable
fun HeaderComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AsyncImage(
        model = R.drawable.landscape11,
        contentDescription = "",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = modifier
            .layout { measurable: Measurable, constraints: Constraints ->

                val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity)
                val placeable = measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
                layout(placeable.width, placeable.height){
                    placeable.placeRelative(0,0)
                }
            }
            .fillMaxWidth()
    )

}

TL/DR2
AsyncImage has different algorithm for calculating painter.intrinsicSize when Constraints has infinite or Constraints.Infinity maxHeight that's why it limits height differently than with finite maxHeight. On the other hand for Image intrinsic size is always dimensions of Bitmap. After further inspection i see that it sets painter.intrinsicSize by keeping fixed dimension while changing infinite one by retaining aspect ratio, but this is never the case with Image or painterResource. painter.intrinsicSize always points to file size.
And AsyncImage intrinsic size returned in LazyColumn has smaller height than Bitmap's height. For a Bitmap with 4256x2832px(1.5f aspect ratio) below on a device with 1080px coil painter size returns 1080x719x(1.5f).
ContentScale calculation
This has nothing to do with ContentScale.Crop. Crop uses functions below to calculate scaledSize or how big Bitmap should be drawn in both Image and AsyncImage implementation
 val Crop = object : ContentScale {
        override fun computeScaleFactor(srcSize: Size, dstSize: Size): ScaleFactor =
            computeFillMaxDimension(srcSize, dstSize).let {
                ScaleFactor(it, it)
            }
    }

private fun computeFillMaxDimension(srcSize: Size, dstSize: Size): Float {
    val widthScale = computeFillWidth(srcSize, dstSize)
    val heightScale = computeFillHeight(srcSize, dstSize)
    return max(widthScale, heightScale)
}

private fun computeFillWidth(srcSize: Size, dstSize: Size): Float =
    dstSize.width / srcSize.width

private fun computeFillHeight(srcSize: Size, dstSize: Size): Float =
    dstSize.height / srcSize.height

Calculating scaledSize or how big a image should be drawn is calculated with computeScaleFactor function.
srcSize is the size of Bitmap while dstSize is the how big Composable should be.
This works exactly same for AsyncImage and Image, however while calculating dstSize AsyncImage uses different algorithm than Image that's why that wide difference in drawn section of Bitmap occurs.
Image vs AsyncImage dstSize
Image calculates maxDimension with
val constrainedHeight = constraints.constrainHeight(intrinsicHeight)

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/PainterModifier.kt;drc=bcee9d46314790d61ccfaa3ed61d33b2e9e90cef;l=287
Which means use smallest height between parent Constraints maxHeight and Bitmap height. If Bitmap height is smaller use that one otherwise use parent dimensions for computing scale factor.
Which results as how Column and LazyColumn fill height but with slight difference
LazyColumn

Column

AsyncImage uses snippet below in ContentPainterModifier.kt
 // Fill the available space if the painter has no intrinsic size.
        val hasBoundedSize = constraints.hasBoundedWidth && constraints.hasBoundedHeight
        val intrinsicSize = painter.intrinsicSize
        if (intrinsicSize.isUnspecified) {
            if (hasBoundedSize) {
                return constraints.copy(
                    minWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                    minHeight = constraints.maxHeight,
                )
            } else {
                return constraints
            }
    }


    // Changed from `PainterModifier`:
    // Use the maximum space as the destination size if the constraints are bounded and at
    // least one dimension is a fixed pixel value. Else, use the intrinsic size of the painter.
    val dstWidth: Float
    val dstHeight: Float
    if (hasBoundedSize && (hasFixedWidth || hasFixedHeight)) {
        dstWidth = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat()
        dstHeight = constraints.maxHeight.toFloat()
    } else {
        val (intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight) = intrinsicSize
        dstWidth = when {
            intrinsicWidth.isFinite() -> constraints.constrainWidth(intrinsicWidth)
            else -> constraints.minWidth.toFloat()
        }
        dstHeight = when {
            intrinsicHeight.isFinite() -> constraints.constrainHeight(intrinsicHeight)
            else -> constraints.minHeight.toFloat()
        }
    }

Which has a different calculation for painter.IntrinsicSize that also calculated, instead of using Bitmap dimensions, then sets dstHeight with constraints.constrainHeight(intrinsicHeight) unlike Image and that's why that big difference happens.
LazyColumn

Column

and the difference between calculating dst height results how image is drawn differently with finite and infinite maxHeight.
Demo to test difference how dstSize is calculated with Image and AsyncImage
@Preview
@Composable
fun ContentScaleTest() {
    LazyColumn (
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        item {
            HeaderComposable()
        }
    }

//    Column  (
//        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
//    ) {
//        HeaderComposable()
//    }
}

@Composable
fun HeaderComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AsyncImage(
        model = R.drawable.landscape11,
        contentDescription = "",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )

//    Image(
//        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.landscape11),
//        contentDescription = "",
//        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
//        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
//    )
}


your answer is very long and complex, and I don't see any solution on it my friend

My answer doesn't offer a solution because there is no ask for solution in the first place. And i put a TL:DR section that explains this happens because AsyncImage uses different algo than Image to calculate dstSize that is passed computeScaleFactor not because Crop as you can see it behaves differently with Image and AsyncImage.

@NullPointerException added solution too. You just need to change maxheight of AsyncImage to Constraints.Infinity for it to calculate computeScaleFactor same as it does with LazyColumn

So there are two solutions:
First ->
You can wrap the AsyncImage in a Box to specify its dimensions explicitly. This way, you can control its height or width.
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(200.dp)) {
AsyncImage(model = imageUrl, contentDescription = null, contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)

Second->
Set Modifier. width() or Modifier.size(): Use the width modifier to set a defined width for your image, preventing it from stretching.
AsyncImage(
model = imageUrl,
contentDescription = null,
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(200.dp),
contentScale = ContentScale.Crop

)
